# I want to remove links which direct us to our browser from my doc. How can do that?

Tags: urls, external-files, links, hyperlink, external

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

% Bitstream Charter
% \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
%for printing \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-7.7mm}
%for pdf \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-12.7mm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.6in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
%\marginparwidth=1pt


\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-6pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black} \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemNoBullet}[2]{
  \item[]\small{
    \hspace{-9pt}\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#3} & \text{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumenewSubheading}[6]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#3} & \text{\small #4} \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\text{\small#5} & \text{\small #6} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


% custom commands
\newcommand{\shorterSection}[1]{\vspace{-10pt}\section{#1}}
\newlength\tindent
\setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{\tindent}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  {}\hspace{6.5cm}\textbf{{\huge First last Name}} &  \\

  \hspace{1.6cm}{fname@university.edu | https://www.linkedin.com}  & {{}}

\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are loading hyperref.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **remove any hyperlinks**, you can simply delete the `\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}` line in your .tex file.

If you want **hyperlinks for other things than external references**, e.g. for hyperfootnotes or your table of contents, you can use the `\nolinkurl{URL}` command around external URLs. The URL will be written in same way as with `\url{}`, without creating a hyperlink, c.f. the [hyperref package documentation, p. 18](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#page=18).

---

In your document, `fname@university.edu` and `https://www.linkedin.com` aren't hyperlinkes at all. The hyperref package only inserts an external hyperlink if you use the `\url{}` or a comparable command. In your case, the useage of `\nolinkurl{}` will help to avoid overfull hbox, but the URLs font will stay the same as in your other text, since you are using the `\urlstyle{same}` option.